# LISP (Add one to the value in the middle of the list)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm currently attempting to create a function that adds 1 to the value that's in the middle of the list.

```
Example: (add1 '(2 4 6 5 9)) -> (2 4 7 5 9)
```

Also if the list is even, it returns nothing. So far I have a function that returns the location of the middle of the list.

```
(defun add1(aList)
               (if (oddp (length aList)) (- (/ (length aList) 2) .5) 'EvenNumber))
```

Example: (add1 '(2 4 6 5 9)) -> 2.0

Is there a way to use this information to get to the value in the middle then add 1 to it. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to modify the list in place, or do you want to return a new list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
(defun add1 (lst)
  (when (oddp (length lst))
    (incf (nth (floor (/ (length lst) 2)) lst)))
  lst)
```

I think the missing piece you need is `setf` (you've probably already used it, but perhaps you didn't know you could use a *form* for the first argument) or in this case `incf` (increments by one or an optional specified delta). They allow you to use an expression to get the value that needs to be set.

Some things to think about (as written):

- This is a destructive update
- It calls `length` multiple times on the same list. This could be expensive.
- As I have written it, even-length lists just return the list unchanged. This is not exactly what you asked for, but perhaps what you wanted.
- I used `floor` instead of messing around with subtracting `.5`, which would necessitate some additional casting.

Comment: You could use `(floor (/ (length lst) 2))`, but the language already  has **truncate**;  e.g., `(truncate (length lst) 2)`.

Comment: As far as I understand, the language has both. `floor` and `truncate` are similar and in the case of positive numbers interchangeable, but behave differently when dealing with negative numbers. `floor` chops toward negative infinity, whereas `truncate` chops toward zero. Since there's no such thing as a negative length list, I'm not sure which one to call more "correct."

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: `(floor (/ n 2))` is equivalent to `(floor n 2)`.

Comment: @Svante (and brian_o), My intent wasn't to highlight the difference between floor and truncate (and since lengths are always a non-negative number, I'm not sure the difference is important);  I probably should have used floor to keep with the answer.  My point was that there's no need to divide *and* floor;  the **floor* function already accepts a divisor argument, so you can do `(floor (length lst) 2)`.

Comment: Oh, awesome! I didn't realize. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
(defun add-1 (list)
  (let ((len (length list)))
    (assert (oddp len) (list))
    (incf (nth (/ (1- len) 2) list))))
```

Replace [`assert`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_assert.htm) with a [`when`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_when_.htm) if you do not want an error on even-length lists.

Comment: Why `assert`? Why not `when`?

Comment: why not? :-) `assert` lets the user supply a new value.

Comment: I understood that an even length list is a valid input.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function which makes only two passes through the list rather than modifying the original, and doesn't perform any arithmetic with integers:

```
(defun inc-middle-elt (list)
  (loop for elem in list
        for pair = list then (cddr pair)
        with flag = t
        when (and flag (null (cddr pair))) do
          (if (null (cdr pair))
            (incf elem))
          (setf flag nil)
        collect elem))
```

For finding the middle, this uses a similar trick to what is used in implementations of the binary merge sort for linked lists: an auxiliary pointer `pair` walks through the list at double stride, stepping over pairs.

We are at the last pair when `(cddr pair)` is `nil`. At that point, a decision must be made: does the list have an odd number of items or not? If the list has an odd number of items, then at the last pair position, where `(cddr pair)` is `nil`, only one element remains: `(cdr pair)` is also nil.

Exercise: optimize this function by taking advantage of the fact that the elements after the middle of the list need not be copied; the output list can share the tail portion of the input list. Also, change the function so that when it is clear there is no middle element, it returns the original list.

Comment: There is no efficiency gain over first saving `(length list)` in a variable, then `incf`ing the right `nth` if odd.

Comment: @Svante You're describing something other than what is implemented in this answer: namely, a destructive function. There is no efficiency gain over that because here were a consing up a whole entire list.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you are looking for a **recursive version**,

```
(defun middle (lis)
 (let ((lis (c-in-place lis)))
  (cond ((null lis) nil) ((atom lis) lis)
   (t
    (mapcar
     #'(lambda (x)
        (cond ((atom x) x) (t (mapcar #'c-in-place (c-in-place x)))))
     lis)))))


(defun c-in-place (lis)
 (cond
  ((and (listp lis) (oddp (length lis)) (> (length lis) 2))
   (let ((pos (1+ (floor (/ (length lis) 2)))))
    (in-place (1+ (nth (floor (/ (length lis) 2)) lis)) pos lis)))
  (t lis)))

(defun in-place (nxt n lis)
 (let (temp temp1) (setf temp (subseq lis 0 (- n 1)))
  (setf temp1 (subseq lis n)) (setf temp (append temp (append `(,nxt) temp1)))
  temp))
```

Usage:

1. `(middle '((1 4 6 7 8) (3 4 2)))` =>`((1 4 7 7 8) (3 5 2))`
2. `(middle '((1 4 6 7) (3 4 2)))` => `((1 4 6 7) (3 5 2))`
3. `(middle '(2 3 4))` => `(2 4 4)`
4. `(middle '(2 3 4 5)` => `(2 3 4 5)`